# PHP Equivalent of Coldfusion's cfpdfform

Tags: javascript, php, json, pdf, coldfusion

I have a legal application using government forms.  These forms are fill in PDFs (FDF Data).

We have sets of data in JSON format stored in a database.  I want to be able to take that data an insert it into the fill-in pdf.  Coldfusion's cfpdfform seems to do that quite well.  However Coldfusion appears to me to have some off-beat JSON formatting.

So, my request is simply, what is the best way to populate a pdf fill-in form with data in PHP or javascript?

In the alternative, our json data contains a number of objects and arrays within it.  Is there any, non-tedious way of getting Coldfusion to understand its formatting without numerous cfloops within the datafile to get it into a struct?

Thanks so much.

Comment: It's impossible to comment on your fourth para without knowing what the data structure is and what problem you're having with it. That said, that's probably a separate question, mostly unrelated to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project spec last year. We had a 50-page legacy fillable pdf form that we wanted to bring up-to-date and integrate into a panel review workflow. I hit countless roadblocks, mostly due to end-user environments.

My ultimate solution was slightly out-of-the-box, but you may consider something similar: 
I built the actual interactive form as a traditional HTML5\jQuery\CSS3 view that contained the form and methods for loading and saving form data to SQL. The business logic employed TCPDF (I think that's the lib I used - maybe FPDF of something like that) and an alternate stylesheet that re-renders the form data to classic, printable PDF.

I can't **promise** this is the best solution for your situation, but it nailed it for us.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at our [SetaPDF-FormFiller](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component (not free!). It allows you to fill in PDF forms in pure PHP.

You only need a kind of mapping logic from your json-objects to the PDF form field names. The filing process is that simple:

```
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('pdf-form-filled.pdf');
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('pdf-form.pdf', $writer);
$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
$fields['name']->setValue($jsonData->name);
$fields['gender']->setValue($jsonData->gender);
...
$document->save()->finish();
```

Comment: You should always disclose when an answer directs someone to your own product. Not to imply the answer is right or wrong, but it is the professional thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I thought that was clear by the link/logo/name... I just updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed, the similarity in names was my clue but similarity happens. I hovered ove the link and realized. However others may not. Cheers!